# How can I submit a form with ajax for appended items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, submit

The click works for the initially loaded elements in the dom but when I try clicking the recently appended items it does not work. I have tried `.live`, `.delegate` and `.on` and they do not work at all. Here is the code:

I used this and it did not work, it still does a page refresh:

```
$('.forms').on('click', '.button-like', function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent('.forms');
    var $thisItem = $parent.find('.button-like');
    console.log($parent);
    $(this).submit(function () {
        var data = {
            "action": "like"
        };
        data = $parent.serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        var itemId = $parent.find('input.id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/actions/",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Like submitted successfully sent');
                //$thisItem.addClass('isliked');
                $thisItem.after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-unlike unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>');
                $thisItem.remove();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $(this).submit();
});
```

This above code does not work at all with newly added items to the page, it keeps refreshing the page?

Here is the append code for your interest:

```
success: function(data) {
            // Output data
            $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
            var $content = $('<article class="instagram-image"><form id="'+ data.images[i].data_token +'" class="forms status-'+ data.images[i].data_like +'" action="'+base+'" method="post"><a class="fancybox" href="'+ data.images[i].data_link +'"><img alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" src="' + data.images[i].data_url + '" alt="' + data.images[i].data_text + '" /></a><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+ data.images[i].data_id +'"><p>'+ data.images[i].data_likes +'</p></form></article>');
              $('section#images').append($content);
              if( $content.find('form').hasClass("status-false") ){
                    $content.find('form').addClass("notLiked");
                    //$('.notLiked').find('button.unlike').hide();
                    $content.find('form a').after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-like like icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Like"></button>');
                }
                if( $content.find('form').hasClass("status-true") ){
                    $content.find('form').addClass("Liked");
                    //$('.Liked').find('button.like').hide();
                    $content.find('form a').after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-unlike unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>');
                }
              });
            // Store new maxid
            $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
          }
```

I have tried absolutely everything and it still wont work. I wondered if it was the logic that is wrong?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: Here `this` refers to the button (submit???) not the form. The onsubmit handler must be applied to the form, not the button. BTW, on your code, $thisItem == $(this)

Comment: Can I just ask how that would work? In my on click it sets it to the form and then I delegate .button-like to be the click handler and then that submits the form. I tried changing `$(this).submit` to `$('.button-like')` and nothing changed at all it still refreshes the page!

Comment: If `.forms`, its a `FORM-TAG` then just use your `$parent`, so `$parent.submit(...`

Comment: Like i said and like @reyaner comment, the onsubmit is for the form, not the button. BTW, nesting a handler inside an other one is just wrong. You should use your console to check which element is targeted by which variable and you should see where your problems come from.

Comment: @reyaner Be careful with '.parent()'. It won't work if the submit button is not a children from form tag. In my eyes '$(this).parents("form:first")' is more save.

Comment: @reporter correct but .closest() is better than parents() here

Comment: So `$parent.submit();` should not be in there then?

Comment: No, because each time you'll click on the submit button, a new handler will be attached to the form. So, if you click twice, the form will be submited twice

Comment: The on click still doesn't work for new appended items

Answer (score 0):

Would this work maybe?

```
$('.forms').submit(function() {
    var $parent = $(this);
    var $button = $parent.find('.button-like');

    var data = {
        "action": "like"
    };
    data = $parent.serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    var itemId = $parent.find('input.id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/actions/",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Like submitted successfully sent');
            //$thisItem.addClass('isliked');
            $button.after('<button class="ajax instabtn button-unlike unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>');
            $button.remove();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Suppose this would not get over the fact that newly appended items on the DOM are not taking this script and using ajax to post the form

Comment: i thout new content is in `.forms`... so you could use then a parent-warpper, that is not getting loaded, and go with `$("parent-warpper").on("submit", ".forms"`...